# How to insert into a table when subquery return more value?

Tags: sql-server

Hi I crate have a Split function that return rows like bellow :

```
declare @a nvarchar(50)= '1,2,3,4,5,6'
select Item from dbo.Split(@a,',')
```

Result :

```
Item
--------
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Now I want create a table and insert into two field from my split function like below :

```
declare @a nvarchar(50)= '1,2,3,4,5,6'
declare @b nvarchar(50)= '10,20,30,40,50,60'

declare @tblCare table
(
    id int , 
    count int
)

insert into @tblCare (id,count) 
values 
(
   (select Item from dbo.Split(@a,',')),
   (select Item from dbo.Split(@b,','))
)

select * from @tblCare
```

and I get this

> Error :  Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 Subquery returned more
>   than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=,
>   <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The
>   statement has been terminated.

```
id          count
----------- -----------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

and its my expect result :

```
id     count
---------------
1   10  
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   50
6   60
```

Comment: what is your expected output?  6x6 entries or total 6 corresponding entries ?

Comment: Your split function returns an entire result set and you are trying to insert that into an integer column of one row. That is why you are getting the "Subquery returned more than one row" error. I'm assuming your split function returns values in order that they appear in the comma separated list. If that is the case, then maybe use ROW_NUMBER against the returned values and join the two results of the functions based upon the row number (so element 1 of @a relates to element 1 of @b).

Comment: It would be better to use datatypes in SQL that are *designed* for holding multiple values, rather than stuffing things into strings and then fighting to undo the problem of your own creation. The types *designed* for holding multiple values are xml and tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
declare @t1 table (ID bigint identity(1, 1), Item nvarchar(max))
declare @t2 table (ID bigint identity(1, 1), Item nvarchar(max))

insert into @t1
select item from dbo.Split(@a,',')

insert into @t2
select item from dbo.Split(@b,',')      

insert into @tblCare (id,count)
select T1.Item, T2.Item
from @t1 as T1 
    inner join @t2 as T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Here first I'm creating tables with identity column to enumerate rows of your splitted data.

And then just joining two results using these rownumbers and inserting it.

Answer (score 4):

Your `dbo.Split` function should return a `serial no` on which we can join the two splits. I am using [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden which is one of the fastest splitter there is, but you can update your split function to include a serial number using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
declare @a nvarchar(50)= '1,2,3,4,5,6'
declare @b nvarchar(50)= '10,20,30,40,50,60'

insert into @tblCare (id,count)
SELECT a.item,b.item 
FROM [DelimitedSplit8K](@a,',')  a
INNER JOIN [DelimitedSplit8K](@b,',') b
ON a.itemnumber = b.itemnumber
```

**Output**

```
1   10
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   50
6   60
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a subquery, the insert syntax form:

```
insert into table ...
select ...
```

Where the number and type of the select columns matches the inserted columns.

I have assumed you want a count from all calls to split of the items returned:

```
insert into @tblCare (id, count) 
select item, count(*) from
(select item from dbo.Split(@a,',')
union all
select item from dbo.Split(@b,',')) x
group by item
```

Comment: OP is trying to insert into 2 columns in `@tblCare`. I think he wants 6 corresponding rows to be inserted

Comment: I want inser @a into id and @b into count !!

Comment: @mohammad - Do you want first value of @a to be inserted along with first value of @b or all values of @b? i.e. do you want 6X6 rows or 6 rows as output

Comment: @mohammad oh - I assume they are to be joined using their row number?

Comment: That was my initial thought, but I'm not even sure you could rely on row_number could you? Using ROW_NUMBER would mean that order needs to be guaranteed. Is an ORDER BY clause allowed in a function? Only if you use dodgy `SELECT TOP 100%` type clauses.